# Can magnetic fields be used to either strengthen or weaken chemical bonds?

Tags: physics, chemistry, materials, electromagnetism

My understanding is that magnetic fields compress atoms slightly. Could this conceivably be used in combination with certain substances with very specific properties to strengthen them in the presence of the field? (Not with present technology, but for a sufficiently advanced civilization).

Alternatively, could this effect be used to weaken chemical bonds in most substances?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. We do things differently than other Q&A sites. In addition to restricting the topics that can be discussed here, we also restrict the type of questions that can be asked. You can learn more by taking the [tour], or visiting the [help] and [meta]. This isn't the place to ask about real world chemistry try https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ instead. If you [edit] your question to make it more about a specific worldbuilding issue you're having, we'd be happy to help you resolve it.

Comment: Search terms: "magnetic selectivity magnet" [magnetically modulated...](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2589004221004260)[magnetic field alters ...](https://www.mdpi.com/2312-7481/9/3/65)  Their were many hits. In other words you can use magnets to later reactions. Also have you not been introduced to microwave ovens? They are pretty direct in manipulation of polar molecules via EM.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it can, but not the way you think. The strength of magnetic fields is largely ignored by chemistry, but the gradient isn't.

Molecules are held onto each other through what we call "van der Waals" forces. These are variations in magnetic field at an inter-molecular level. They are subdivided into dipole-dipole bonds (strongest), hydrogen bonds, and London Dispersion forces (weakest), but it's all still variations of magnetic field. If you were to spin a magnet on an axis orthogonal to the magnetic poles at a speed where it surface approached the speed of light, it would create magnetic waves that would overwhelm London Dispersion forces.

There are two problems with this idea. The first is that we have no magnets that can spin that fast without flying apart. The second is that whatever did the spinning would be the first thing to explode. It might make an interesting bomb.

Comment: Thank you for the fascinating siggestions!

Comment: Do you have to actually spin the magnet?  Or would finding a way to flicker an electromagnet on and off at an insanely high frequency do the trick?

Comment: @Perkins, that's what magnetic resonance imaging does. I don't believe that would work because the power gradient wouldn't have time to build across the wire within the switching time. This is also a limit to the switching speed of modern microprocessors.

Comment: [Johannes Diderik van der **Waals**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Diderik_van_der_Waals) was a Dutch physicist; he was awarded the Nobel Prize for physics in 1910. The van der **Waals** intermolecular forces are named after him.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexP. Maybe I'll remember that this time.

Comment: @RobertRapplean True.  There is probably a limit there.  I thought of it mostly due to a couple of old patents I saw that appeared to be using what we now know as magnetic resonance tuned to hit the natural frequency of particular atoms in a way that would boost radioactive decay.  But that only requires switching in the megahertz range. I wonder if there's some subharmonic of whatever the "spinning at the speed of light" frequency is that would work if you poured enough juice into it...

Comment: Curiously, I always remember van der Waals, but I always misspell [van de(r) Gra(a)f(f)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_J._Van_de_Graaff)...

Comment: @Perkins just use light. Photochemistry is a thing.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Yes, but light has much more limited penetration, so it depends on just what you're trying to do engineering-wise as well.

Comment: @Perkins, There are many, many things that could do more damage with less energy. I'm really stretching things to cause damage here, even at high energy levels. It would be far easier to use microwaves at the resonant frequency of water molecules, but that's not what OP asked. :)

Comment: @RobertRapplean  He's asking if you could strengthen or weaken materials with magnetic fields.  There are definitely more efficient ways to cause damage for most applications if gross damage is your primary goal -- even just magnetic induction heating.  But there might be specific engineering applications for manipulating bonds with magnetic fields or similar. I recall one story where aliens sell humans a device that lets you soften metal to putty without heating it and then harden it again on demand for instance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can induce a circulating current in aromatic chemicals pi orbitals if they go in loops. It should be possible to link one flux quantum with a benzine ring, but this would put a lot of stress in it, and I don't know if it would be stable. You would probably have a better chance of making a stable organic magnet if you used a larger ring. An 18-element ring such as a porphyrin ought to link one flux quantum stably at room temperature, and be stiff enough to keep it, but I have never had a chance to try it.